# Extracting Info from detectron2 panoptic segmentation and using it to mask a particular object in an image

Tags: python, object-detection, mask, image-segmentation, detectron

In theory, I'd like to emulate what is done at the beginning of this blog: https://www.sicara.fr/blog-technique/dataset-generation-fine-tune-stable-diffusion-inpainting

I need to do it using detectron2 so as to use the capability of it panoptic segmentation.

However, I'm struggling to correctly extract information (bounding coordinates, class-labels, etc.) after the image has been processed through the panoptic checkpoint.

I need these bits of information if I'm to target a particular object to be masked as in the blog.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from detectron2 import model_zoo
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2.engine import DefaultPredictor
from detectron2.utils.visualizer import Visualizer
from detectron2.data import MetadataCatalog

width, height = 512, 512

# Load the Panoptic Segmentation model
cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file("COCO-PanopticSegmentation/panoptic_fpn_R_50_3x.yaml"))
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = model_zoo.get_checkpoint_url("COCO-PanopticSegmentation/panoptic_fpn_R_50_3x.yaml")
predictor = DefaultPredictor(cfg)

# Load the input image
image = cv2.imread("dog.jpg")

# Preprocess the image (resize, convert to RGB)
image = cv2.resize(image, (width, height))
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Perform panoptic segmentation
panoptic_output = predictor(image)

# Get the panoptic segmentation instances
instances = panoptic_output["instances"]

# Visualize the predictions
v = Visualizer(image[:, :, ::-1], MetadataCatalog.get(cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN[0]), scale=1.2)
v = v.draw_panoptic_seg_predictions(panoptic_output["panoptic_seg"], instances)
output_image = v.get_image()[:, :, ::-1]

# Create a mask image of the same size as the input image
mask_image = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)

# Get the panoptic segmentation mask
panoptic_mask = instances.pred_masks.numpy()

# Iterate over the panoptic segmentation mask and extract the mask of dogs
for idx, mask in enumerate(panoptic_mask):
    if instances.pred_classes[idx] == 16:  # Assuming class ID 16 represents dogs
        mask_image += mask.astype(np.uint8) * 255

# Perform translation on the mask image
mask_image += np.roll(mask_image, 10, axis=0)  # Translate the mask 10 pixels to the left
mask_image += np.roll(mask_image, -10, axis=0)  # Translate the mask 10 pixels to the right
mask_image += np.roll(mask_image, 10, axis=1)  # Translate the mask 10 pixels to the bottom
mask_image += np.roll(mask_image, -10, axis=1)  # Translate the mask 10 pixels to the top

# Set non-black pixels to white pixels
mask_image = np.clip(mask_image, 0, 255)

# Save the mask image
cv2.imwrite("mask_image.jpg", mask_image)
```

I keep getting errors everywhere. Here's an example:
return _VF.meshgrid(tensors, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Daniel Kolb\Moreland-Connect\SD-Housing-Proj\Diffusers\test.py", line 32, in 
v = v.draw_panoptic_seg_predictions(panoptic_output["panoptic_seg"], instances)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "c:\users\daniel kolb\moreland-connect\sd-housing-proj\diffusers\detectron2\detectron2\utils\visualizer.py", line 488, in draw_panoptic_seg
pred = _PanopticPrediction(panoptic_seg, segments_info, self.metadata)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "c:\users\daniel kolb\moreland-connect\sd-housing-proj\diffusers\detectron2\detectron2\utils\visualizer.py", line 186, in **init**
self._sinfo = {s["id"]: s for s in segments_info}  # seg id -> seg info
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "c:\users\daniel kolb\moreland-connect\sd-housing-proj\diffusers\detectron2\detectron2\structures\instances.py", line 151, in **iter**
raise NotImplementedError("`Instances` object is not iterable!")
NotImplementedError: `Instances` object is not iterable!

Answer (score 0):

`detectron2` has been updated so that the `panoptic_seg` key from the predictor outputs both the panoptic segmentation labels and the segments info. As such, you should update it to this:

```
# Get the panoptic segmentation instances
panoptic_seg, segments_info = panoptic_output["panoptic_seg"]

# Visualize the predictions
v = Visualizer(image[:, :, ::-1], MetadataCatalog.get(cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN[0]), scale=1.2)
v = v.draw_panoptic_seg_predictions(panoptic_seg, segments_info)
```